# как в процессе ввода записать записать информацию в строку?

Tags: java

Нужна помощь, как в процессе ввода записать все стрелки в строку, и вывести их в консоль после цикла ?

```
package home_work_string_equals_arrows;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Home_Work_String_Equals_Arrows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String s = sc.next();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                System.out.println('\u2190');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                System.out.println('\u2192');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {
                System.out.println('\u2191');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {
                System.out.println('\u2193');
            }
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлять в строку и вывести после цикла. А в чем проблема?

Comment: Используйте класс StringBuilder

Comment: Можно перед циклом инициализировать `String str = '';` переменную и в цикле уже просто обновлять ее значение `str += s;` и потом спокойно после цыкла ее выводить, к примеру.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov обратите внимание на первую строчку в psvm.

Comment: @Эникейщик вижу, но он не используется. Только объявлен.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Ха, действительно.

Comment: Да я вижу про StringBuilder но он выводит только слова (left right и т.д.), а надо что бы выводил стрелки

Comment: @ЕвгенийВалерьевич StringBuilder у вас никак не используется. Выводите вы другими средствами и выводите на экран. Используйте метод `append()` для того чтобы в экземпляр StringBuilder по имени sb записывать символы стрелок в нужном случае. А когда цикл закончится выводите на экран содержимое `sb.toString()`. Вот тут почитайте: http://cybern.ru/java-stringbuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Все решил всем спасибо за помощь =)
вот решение кому интересно

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String s = sc.next();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                System.out.println('\u2190');
                sb.append('\u2190');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                System.out.println('\u2192');
                sb.append('\u2192');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {
                System.out.println('\u2191');
                sb.append('\u2191');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {
                System.out.println('\u2193');
                sb.append('\u2193');
            }
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        System.out.println(sb);
```